# Finding radius of an exoplanet's orbit knowing orbital period and star's mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astronomy, exoplanets

I've been stuck on this question in an assignment for a while now, and I can't seem to find anything on the internet that either deals with a question in which more values are provided, or where the answer is well beyond the scope of the course I'm in (first year astronomy).

I'll avoid inputting values in an effort to not violate any academic integrity things with my school, but I'm just at a loss for exactly how to approach this question with the values given:

*Astronomers discover an exoplanet that has an orbital distance of (number provided) Earth years in its circular orbit around its sun, which is a star with a mass of (number provided) kg. Find the radius of the exoplanet's orbit.*

Also, the provided hint is "How do the exoplanet's orbital period and the mass of its sun relate to its orbital radius?", which I'm curious about, but I don't know. My textbook isn't much help.

I'd think that you'd use Kepler's third law/Newton's interpretation of said law, but not knowing the mass of the exoplanet seems to rule that out. I also thought that if the orbit is circular and we know the orbital distance, couldn't we just find the radius via that (meaning the mass of its sun is a red herring)?

I'm sure I'm overlooking something trivial, but does anyone have an explanation of how to work this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: That said: $M+m\approx M$ is often an okay approximation for stars ($M$) and their planets ($m$).

Comment: 5 seconds of googling: http://www.physicsclassroom.com/calcpad/circgrav

Comment: As the link above notes, R^3/T^2 (orbital radius cubed over period squared) is a constant for all planets in a given system, and that constant is proportional to the sun's mass (I flipped the equation in the link to get this equivalent but better-sounding result). For the sun, this is 1 astronomical unit cubed over 1 year squared (by definition) for Earth, and thus the same for all other planets.

Answer (score 0):

You would most definitely use Kepler's third law. With almost all planets, the mass of the planet is negligible so it is ignored.

We know the orbital period and the mass. Use those and Kepler's third law to write an equation for the orbital radius.